# Check that variable is in an array

Tags: php

Possibly already been asked but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

How can I check that a variable is in an array?

Here is my code so far - ideally I wan't to echo out something when the ProductID also exists in the lastUpdatedProduct array as well as the productOptions array.

```
<?php if ($this->productOptions) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->productOptions as $options) {
        $array = $this->lastUpdatedProduct;
        echo '<strong>' . $options['ProductID'] . '</strong>';
            if(in_array($options['CentreID'], $array)) {
                echo 'it exists';
            }
        }
    }?>
```

Heres my array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '391' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '467' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '474' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '2985' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '2985' (length=4)
  5 => 
    array
      'pid' => string '424' (length=3)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: Please explain your question properly, what you are trying to do has been accomplished by following the link provided by Ryan J and I think you also followed that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$array` is an array with arrays and you are trying to find something inside one of the inner arrays. Try with this:

```
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if (is_array($entry) && in_array($options['CentreID'], $entry))
        echo 'it exists';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I wan't to echo out something when the ProductID is in the array

```
if(is_array($options['ProductID'])) { }
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/187254)

## Edit

> Ideally I wan't to echo out something when the ProductID also exists in the lastUpdatedProduct array as well as the productOptions array.

```
if(is_array($this->productOptions)) { 
     foreach($array as $pid) {
       if(in_array($pid, $options['ProductID'])) {
          //echo
       }
     }
}
```